# How to send Gunicorn Error Logs to a file and to stdout?

Tags: python, file, logging, stdout, gunicorn

I undertsand that:

- In order to send Gunicorn Error Logs to a file, the file name must be mentioned in
  gunicorn configuration file as `errorlog = "<filepath>"`
  OR
- In order to send Gunicorn Error Logs to a stdout, '-' must be mentioned in
  gunicorn configuration file as `errorlog = "-"`

BUT is it possible to do both? If yes, then how?

Nothing is clearly mentioned in the documentation.
I have configured my flask app logger to write error logs to the stdout by adding a stdout_streamhandler to the gunicorn logger, This means when the app is running, logs from gunicorn get written to the file and to stdout, as shown below:

```
import logging  # pylint: disable=R0801
import sys
from logging import handlers

def _get_stream_handler():
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    _log_format = "[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)s - %(process)s: %(message)s"
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format, datefmt=_datefmt))
    return stream_handler

def get_logger(name):
    stdout_stream_handler = _get_stream_handler()
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(_get_file_handler())
    logger.addHandler(stdout_stream_handler)
    gunicorn_error_logger = logging.getLogger("gunicorn.error")
    gunicorn_error_logger.addHandler(stdout_stream_handler)
    return logger
```

But when gunicorn is run with `--reload = True`, and there is an error in the code, the worker does not boot up and so the app logger doesnt get enabled, in this situation the logs get written to the file mentioned in errorlog "", but not to stdout because the app is not loaded and hence there is no app logger. Is there a way to enable this from outside the app using a gunicorn configfile or some other way.